# How to use two database one for development and other production in the same application django

Tags: django, django-models, multiple-databases

I have two databases one for development and other for the production, i set two dbs in my settings, but how can i alternate between the two dbs. Now i use method using in all objects, but i dont know if it`sthe best form.

settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': os.getenv('DB_PRODUCTION_ENGINE', 'change-me'),
        'NAME': os.getenv('POSTGRES_PRODUCTION_DB', 'change-me'),
        'USER': os.getenv('POSTGRES_PRODUCTION_DB_USER', 'change-me'),
        'PASSWORD': os.getenv('POSTGRES_PRODUCTION_DB_PASSWORD', 'change-me'),
        'HOST': os.getenv('POSTGRES_PRODUCTION_HOST', 'change-me'),
        'PORT': os.getenv('POSTGRES_PRODUCTION_PORT', 'change-me'),
    },
    'development': {
        'ENGINE': os.getenv('DB_DEVELOPMENT_ENGINE', 'change-me'),
        'NAME': os.getenv('POSTGRES_DEVELOPMENT_DB', 'change-me'),
        'USER': os.getenv('POSTGRES_DEVELOPMENT_DB_USER', 'change-me'),
        'PASSWORD': os.getenv('POSTGRES_DEVELOPMENT_DB_PASSWORD', 'change-me'),
        'HOST': os.getenv('POSTGRES_DEVELOPMENT_HOST', 'change-me'),
        'PORT': os.getenv('POSTGRES_DEVELOPMENT_PORT', 'change-me'),
    }
}
```

example queryset

```
def get_database_name(request):
    environment = request.session.get('environment', 'default')
    return environment

using = get_database_name(request)
model = Model.objects.using(using)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can switch between the two dbs via the settings.py file. Locally DEBUG is set to true and in production that is set to false. With this in mind:

```py
if DEBUG:
    DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': os.getenv('DB_DEVELOPMENT_ENGINE', 'change-me'),
        'NAME': os.getenv('POSTGRES_DEVELOPMENT_DB', 'change-me'),
        'USER': os.getenv('POSTGRES_DEVELOPMENT_DB_USER', 'change-me'),
        'PASSWORD': os.getenv('POSTGRES_DEVELOPMENT_DB_PASSWORD', 'change-me'),
        'HOST': os.getenv('POSTGRES_DEVELOPMENT_HOST', 'change-me'),
        'PORT': os.getenv('POSTGRES_DEVELOPMENT_PORT', 'change-me'),
    }
}
else:
    DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': os.getenv('DB_PRODUCTION_ENGINE', 'change-me'),
        'NAME': os.getenv('POSTGRES_PRODUCTION_DB', 'change-me'),
        'USER': os.getenv('POSTGRES_PRODUCTION_DB_USER', 'change-me'),
        'PASSWORD': os.getenv('POSTGRES_PRODUCTION_DB_PASSWORD', 'change-me'),
        'HOST': os.getenv('POSTGRES_PRODUCTION_HOST', 'change-me'),
        'PORT': os.getenv('POSTGRES_PRODUCTION_PORT', 'change-me'),
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks you for your help! but i would like alternate with two databases in runtime, for example: The user goes to url /environment and see two buttons development and production, when click anyone set the database and go to home page.